# C++ conditional waiting stops execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I have the following class method:

```
myclass::concurFnc(bool changingVar )
{
    int i;
    mIdMutex.lock();
    i = mId++;
    mIdMutex.unlock;

    std::cout << "Try Waiting: " << i << std::endl;
    std::mutex waitValidMutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(waitValidMutex);
    mNoOtherThreadDiffCompareVal.wait(l, [this, &changingVar]()
    {
        mSemMutex.lock();
        bool result = false;
        if(myclass::staticVar == changingVar)
        {
            std::cout << "Same var : " << changingVar << i << std::endl;
            result = true;
            --mSem;
        } else if(mSem == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Only one in crit section: " << i << std::endl;
            --mSem;
            myclass::staticVar = changingVar;
            result = true;
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "wait: " << i << std::endl;
            result = false;
        }
        std::cout << "Sem is now " << mSem << std::endl;
        mSemMutex.unlock();
        return result;
    });

    //DO STUFF

    mSemMutex.lock();
    ++mSem;
    std::cout << "In the end sem is: " << mSem << std::endl;
    mSemMutex.unlock();
    mNoOtherThreadDiffCompareVal.notify_all();
}

//class Member Variables
std::mutex mSemMutex;
std::mutex mIdMutex;
std::condition_variable mNoOtherThreadDiffCompareVal;
int32_t mSem;
int32_t mId;

myclass::myclass() : mSem(1), mId(0)
{
}

void myclass::startThreads()
{
    const int AMOUNT_OF_PROCESSES = 3
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > processes;
    for (size_t t_id = 0; t_id < AMOUNT_OF_PROCESSES; ++t_id) 
    {
        bool changingVar = getVarSomewhere();
        std::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_ptr(new boost::thread(&myclass::concurFnc, this, changingVar));
        processes.push_back(thread_ptr);
    }

    for (size_t t_id = 0; t_id < AMOUNT_OF_PROCESSES; ++t_id) {
        processes[t_id]->join();
    }
}
```

It should allow to enter the //DO STUFF section if changingVar is the same as for all other callers who are currently inside //DO STUFF (or if its the only one)
The function is called concurrent from functions in boost::threads.

Sometimes it happenes that the execution stops because it keeps on waiting although mSem is 1 and notify_all() should have been called

Output before execution stops is:

```
wait: 3248
Sem is now 0
Try Waiting: 3249
wait: 3249
Sem is now 0
In the end sem is: 1
Only one in crit section: 3249
Sem is now 0
Try Waiting: 3250
wait: 3250
Sem is now 0
In the end sem is: 1
Only one in crit section: 3250
Sem is now 0
In the end sem is: 1
Try Waiting: 3251
Same comp val : 0 of: 3251
Sem is now 0
.In the end sem is: 1
```

Up to now i could not really reproduce it.

The program started to work again.
Mabey it was because i attached gdb to it, or there was somehow a huge delay.

Comment: Perhaps `changingVar` should be passed into `concurFnc` by reference?

Comment: can't really see anything wrong with the code you showed; so the problem must be in the code you did not show...

Comment: What's the purpose of `waitValidMutex`? It isn't shared between any threads.

Comment: Maybe the function is just not called? If the execution is stuck in waiting, there should be `Try Waiting X` without subsequent `Sem is now Y`. Also, you have a data race in `++i;` which is technically UB.

Comment: @JonathanPotter does is make any difference?

Comment: @Pandrei I'm going to add more code

Comment: @molbdnilo does it have to be shared? Is it not sufficient that mNoOtherThreadDiffCompareVal is?

Comment: @AntonSavin I think that Sem is now Y is from another thread than Try Waiting. To bad i didn't add the ID output there. And i will fix the data race

Comment: why are you using wait on L(waitValidMutex) when the .lock() is only called on mSemMutex?

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 Don't understand what you mean.
mSemMutex is used to avoid race conditions when changing mSem.
l is used for the condition variable and there should be no lock/unlock necessary

Comment: its strange because waitValidMutex is not shared, so the moment your condition is true, ALL threads will enter and ALL threads will hit mSemMutex.lock().

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 so when i call notify_all it won't check the condition again? I just thought sharing the waitValidMutex prevents the waiting conditions from checking at the same time.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 if i share waitValidMutex i think i couldn't simultaneously execute the //DO STUFF area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage pattern for the condition variable is very strange.

The mutex passed in to the `wait` function for the condition variable should always be the one that protects the condition that you are waiting for, which seems to be `mSemMutex` here.

This makes sense since for checking whether the awaited condition is fulfilled, you need to lock this mutex anyway. With that in mind, you can probably get rid of `waitValidMutex` completely and replace all of its uses by `mSemMutex`.

Also note that currently, since `waitValidMutex` is a local mutex, you actually [risk undefined behavior when calling `wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait):

> Calling this function if lock.mutex() is not the same mutex as the one
>   used by all other threads that are currently waiting on the same
>   condition variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Because I don't share waitValidMutex I experience concurrency.
I checked it via adding more output.
I'm not waiting for mSemMutex since it should be possible to enter //DO STUFF when staticVar and changingVar are equal

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not notice that the mutex was local. In that case, things are actually worse. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Oh okey than condition variables are not the way to go here.
I will stick to a polling loop